# how to avoid Ampersand(&) being converted to &amp in c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use MVC model to make the image url and to display it .

I make the image url  like this:

```
        string baseURL = string.Format("https://abc/Work/LookPage?pbid={0}", model.ID);

        var builder = new UriBuilder(baseURL);
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
        query["pg"] = "1";
        query["isStage"] = "false";
        builder.Query = query.ToString();
        model.ImageUrls.Add(1, builder.ToString());
```

and I have a controller named WorkController

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByParam = "*", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client)]
    public virtual ActionResult LookPage(string pbid, int pg, bool? isbody, bool? isStage)
    {
        var ms = this.CreateLookPageImage(pbid, pg, isbody, isStage, false);

        if (ms == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "image/jpeg");

    }
```

and in the view , i write like this:

```
<a><img class="shadow" src="<%:Model.ImageUrls[1] %>"/></a>
```

This worked actually.
but sometimes this error comes:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

at System.Web.HttpCookieCollection.Add(HttpCookie cookie)
   at CWorks.Web.Filter.SiteSelectorAttribute.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)

```
[Request.RawUrl]/Work/LookPage?pbid=PBER-2972311310171610590&amp;pg=8&amp;isStage=true
```

because & in the url is being converted to &amp; so the routing doesnot work.
how can i  avoid the  Ampersand(&) being converted to &amp??

I also donot know why sometimes the url is ok(`&`) and sometime is not(being converted)

Answer (score 7):

Try this. It converts encoded string into decoded html mark up. i.e removes `&amp;` and replaces with `'&'`

```
Html.Raw(Model.ImageUrls[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx

```
<a><img class="shadow" src="<%= Html.Raw(Model.ImageUrls[1]) %>"/></a>
```